# Disable Powershell XML Output in Gitlab Runner Console

Tags: powershell, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When I run a gitlab CI Job with the powershell executor the output is littered with XML Output from what looks like Powershell itself.

```
#< CLIXML
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><Obj S="progress" RefId="0"><TN RefId="0"><T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T><T>System.Object</T></TN><MS><I64 N="SourceId">1</I64><PR N="Record"><AV>Preparing modules for first use.</AV><AI>0</AI><Nil /><PI>-1</PI><PC>-1</PC><T>Completed</T><SR>-1</SR><SD> </SD></PR></MS></Obj></Objs>
```

I was expecting `Set-Variable ProgressPreference SilentlyContinue` to solve this issue but it seems to have no effect. What is the problem here? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Is your gitlab-runner.exe updated? This has been an issue before.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/29462